# why @Request Mapping is not working?

Tags: java, spring

This my request url from which i'm accessing controller

```
<li><a href="brands.htm/nokia">Nokia </a></li>
<li><a href="brands.htm/apple">Apple </a></li>
```

Controller
---------------

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value= "/brands.htm")
public class ShowBrandsProducts {
    @Autowired
    private ECommerceService service;

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getPage() {
        return "shop_brand";
    }


    @RequestMapping("{id}")
    public String getNokia(@PathVariable("id") String brandName, Model model) {
        List<DisplayFeatureProducts> displayList= null;
        List<FeaturedItemsObject> listFeature= new ArrayList<>();
        ByteToImage big= null;

        try {
            //getting all nokia products
            displayList= service.getProductFromBrand(brandName);
        .....

        ......


        model.addAttribute("brand", listFeature);
        return "shop_brand";
    }
```

While giving the request its showing **Request Resource Is Not Available**

Since **/brands.htm** is declaired for another controller to load the default product page where many brands will be displayed.
So when a user clicks on specific brand it should navigate through **brands/nokia** and load the data

Comment: In a traditional web page, it would be `/brands/apple` and the root page would be /brands, with that page being an index.html that is mapped to the path.

Comment: no my url pattern is *.htm in dispatcher servlet

Comment: Try changing  @RequestMapping("{id}") to  @RequestMapping("/{id}")

Comment: that's too not working already tested

Answer (score 1):

Since I can't comment, I will write up an answer. Did you try changing the @RequestMapping(value= "/brands.htm") to @RequestMapping(value= "/brands.htm/"), adding the last slash could work.

Also, is it suppose that both brands.htm and brands.htm/nokia should return the same page (shop_brand)?

Comment: You're on the right track but the usual way is using `@GetMapping("/{id}")` with the leading slash.

Answer (score -1):

One way of achieving the desired functionality is by passing the brand in as a URL parameter. For example:

```
<li><a href="brands.htm?brand=nokia">Nokia </a></li>
<li><a href="brands.htm?brand=apple">Apple </a></li>
```

Then utilize the value of that parameter in the controller/method that handles **/brands.htm** in order to return the applicable page content.

Comment: To use this should I have to use @RequestParam instead of @PathVariable?

Comment: ya i'm aware about this but the above approach should work I have seen in many examples any idea y it's not working